# Linear actuator with low vibration and low noise

Tags: vibration, actuator, linear-motion, linear-motors, noise

Which kinds of linear actuators offer the lowest levels of noise and vibration?

I am looking for an actuator with these properties that can push a load vertically on the cm scale. Velocity, accuracy and max force are secondary. I'd be very glad for a hint to the specific category of actuators that might meet these requirements.

Comment: Audible noise or position/signal or electrical noise?

Comment: @JonathanRSwift audible noise

Answer (score 1):

I might look into medical equipment, I was looking at actuators the other day, and they weren't too expensive.